# undefined method `index_path' using relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get the following error using device and carrierwave gem:

```
undefined method `user_media_index_path'
.Showing .../user_medias/new.html.erb where line #3 raised:
```

I have added index on user_id in user_media model

I have successfully implemented file upload for for single model but I don't know how to do it with a seperate module.

**new.html**

```
form_for @media, :html =>{:multipart =>true} do |f|
  Upload an Image  f.file_field :image
  f.submit 
end
```

This is the user model generated using the device gem:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_many :user_media, dependent: :destroy

end
```

its the model to store the user medias like images,etc i;m using this now only for images
but for future to add more types of media i have created this user_media model

**user_media.rb**

```
class UserMedia < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :anudio, :image, :video
  belongs_to :user

  mount_uploader :image, MediaUploader
end
```

This is where its get redirected to when asked for create action for uploading the image

**user_medias_controller**

```
class UserMediasController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @media = UserMedia.new
  end

  def create
    @media=current_user.user_media.build(params[:media])

    if @media.save
      render'index'
    else
      render'new'
    end
  end
end
```

The routing details are:

**routes.rb**

```
Projectx::Application.routes.draw do
  get "dashboard/index"
  resources :dashboard, :UserMedias
  get "home/index"
  devise_for :users

  root :to => 'home#index'

  match 'uploder' =>'UserMedias#new'
```

**rake routes output** this all after adding resources suggested by @peter

```
         dashboard_index GET    /dashboard/index(.:format)      dashboard#index
                         GET    /dashboard(.:format)            dashboard#index
                         POST   /dashboard(.:format)            dashboard#create
           new_dashboard GET    /dashboard/new(.:format)        dashboard#new
          edit_dashboard GET    /dashboard/:id/edit(.:format)   dashboard#edit
               dashboard GET    /dashboard/:id(.:format)        dashboard#show
                         PUT    /dashboard/:id(.:format)        dashboard#update
                         DELETE /dashboard/:id(.:format)        dashboard#destroy
             user_medias GET    /user_medias(.:format)          user_medias#index
                         POST   /user_medias(.:format)          user_medias#create
          new_user_media GET    /user_medias/new(.:format)      user_medias#new
         edit_user_media GET    /user_medias/:id/edit(.:format) user_medias#edit
              user_media GET    /user_medias/:id(.:format)      user_medias#show
                         PUT    /user_medias/:id(.:format)      user_medias#update
                         DELETE /user_medias/:id(.:format)      user_medias#destroy
              home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)           home#index
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)        devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)        devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)       devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)       devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)   devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)  devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)       devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)         devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)        devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)           devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#destroy
                    root        /                               home#index
                 uploder        /uploder(.:format)              user_medias#new
```

Comment: show us the output for `rake routes`

Answer (score 2):

the error points to a missing route in your routes file.  add this to your routes

```
resources :user_medias
```

Comment: this is probably the right answer.  `form_for(@media)` looks for a route that matches `user_medias_path` via `post` request but since none is declared in your routes, it raises that error.

Comment: Plz/ check above i have added resources :user_medias in routes but not put here. and also the rakr routes output but still same error and by the way i'm using rails 3.2.6.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's got something to do with the name being two words. Did you find a solution to this problem?